# How to Store a Hex Value in a Plist and read in back out again

Tags: objective-c, hex, plist

If been trying to figure this out for ages now and my mind is gone to mush.

What I want to do is store a hex value in NSData in a plist.
I then want to be able to read the hex back out.

I have gotten very confused.

So I try to store the hex value `0x1124`.
When I look in the plist that gets made the value says `24110000`.
And When I print this value I get  `23FA0`

What I want to be able to do is confirm that 0x1124 gets written to my plist and make sure I can print back out the right value.

Im getting the feeling that Im lacking some very fundamental stuff here.

```
NSMutableDictionary  *tempDict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
    // Byte hidService= 1124;
    //int hidService= 00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    unsigned int hidService[]={0x1124};

    NSData  *classlist=[NSData dataWithBytes:&hidService length:sizeof(hidService)];
    NSArray  *classListArray=@[classlist];
    [tempDict setValue:classListArray forKey:kServiceItemKeyServiceClassIDList];

    hidProfileDict=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:tempDict];
    NSLog(@"%X",[hidProfileDict valueForKey:kServiceItemKeyServiceClassIDList][0]);


    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSFileManager  *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"HIDDictionary.plist"];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: plistPath])
    {
        NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HIDDictionary" ofType:@"plist"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:plistPath error:&error];
    }
    [hidProfileDict writeToFile:plistPath atomically: YES];
```

Comment: All I want to do is store a hex value in a plist so that I can load in back as a parameter value to an IOBluetooth that accepts hex values. The hex value in my case that the function expects is 0x1124.

Comment: You need to do some research of what it means for a number to be a hex value. Hint: hex is just a display format of a number the same was as it can be displayed in hex: 1124, binary: 0001000100100100 or decimal: 4388. They are all the same number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x1124` is just a hex representation of the binary bits 0001000100100100 or decimal number 4388. The 0x is just a way to designate the base of the display, it is not part of the number. The number could be expressed in a program in binary with a 0b prefix: `int b = 0b0001000100100100;`. These are all just different representations of the same number.

To add a number to a `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` you need to convert it to an `NSNumber`, the easiest way is to use literal syntax: `@(0x1124)` or `@(4388)`.

Ex:

```
NSArray *a = @[@(0x1124)];
```

or

```
NSDictionary *d = @{kServiceItemKeyServiceClassIDList:@(0x1124)};
// Where kServiceItemKeyServiceClassIDList is defined to be a `NSString`.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store only two bytes use an explicit UInt16 type

```
UInt16 hidService[]={0x1124};
NSData  *classlist = [NSData dataWithBytes:&hidService length:sizeof(hidService)];
```